# Is part P enough to do electrical works in my house?

Tags: electrical

I would like to install a power socket in the shed and I believe I could pull the power from the garage circuit. I've read some treads here and I got a bit confused if I could do it myself or not. But as there are other electrical works to be done, I would like to invest in some domestic electrician course. I know some things that I've learnt on my mechanical engineering degree and worked with a electrician for a couple of months (in Portugal) a few years ago, so not a complete novice. Would I be able to carry out this type of works in my house with the part P course or would need more certifications? This is for UK. Thanks

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I take it you are in the UK from mentioning Part P, no?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. I'm in the UK